# Importing modules that work in Python 2.7 but not Python 3.4

Tags: python

I have previously been using PyCharm with Python 2.7, and have been able to import the module `sklearn`, which was intalled via `sudo apt-get install python-sklearn`.

However, I have now changed the settings in PyCharm to use Python 3.4. Now, it gives me the error: `ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'.`

I suppose this is because `sklearn` was installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. But in `/usr/lib/python3.4`, there is no directory called `dist-packages`. However, I have a directory called `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, which has just one directory, which is `dist-packages`.

Any idea on what I need to do to clean this all up?

Comment: Either: 1. install `sklearn` for the interpreter you want to use; or 2. switch back to the interpreter it's already installed in.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to install `sklearn` for Python 3.4. Ubuntu currently does not have a `python3-sklearn` package available, unfortunately, so you'll have to follow the [installations instructions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html) to install this yourself.

This includes installing build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-setuptools \
                     python3-numpy python3-scipy \
                     libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

You may have to set the right implementation (Ubuntu 13.04 and newer):

```
sudo update-alternatives --set libblas.so.3 \
    /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3
sudo update-alternatives --set liblapack.so.3 \
    /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3
```

followed by

```
pip3 install --user -U scikit-learn
```

for a local install (your account only), or

```
sudo pip3 install -U scikit-learn
```

for a global install.