# pygame module is being imported in python 2.7 but not in 3.x version

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

Here's an [image](https://imgur.com/a/KMayG) of what I have been experiencing

If you find any duplicate question, please link them. I tried searching but found none such for pygame

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996828/importing-modules-that-work-in-python-2-7-but-not-python-3-4) and then tried this:

```
apt-get install build-essential python3-dev python3-setuptools \ python3-pygame
```

but still doesn't work

The error is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package  python3-pygame
```

Please suggest me a way to solve this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't have a python3 pygame package, you may insteadinstall it using `pip`

```
apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev build-essential
pip3 install pygame
```